# Implications of not using repo path for my own packages

Tags: go, structure, organization, tradeoff

Suppose I decide to keep all personally developed packages organized
as follows:

```
$GOPATH/
    bin/
    pkg/
    src/
        somepkg1
        somepkg2
        ...
        somepkgN
```

Further, suppose there is a great deal of code reuse among them, so I
decide to keep the whole $GOPATH workspace under the same Git
repository (each package could be a submodule), as opposed to more
traditional scenario where subpackages are less coherent (co-existing
solely because of using `go get` from the same workspace):

```
$GOPATH/
    bin/
    pkg/
    src/github.com/<me>/
        somepkg1
        somepkg2
        ...
        somepkgN
```

I can see that with the former approach (not using `github.com/<me>/`
in the package paths), `go get` would not be able to fetch packages as
they are not "declaring" themselves to be available online. However,
one can easily work around that by using git submodules, so all
packages would be fetched in the first place (note it's a tightly
controlled ecosystem so there will be no name clashes).

Is there any other limitation (besides `go get`) of not using full
paths for packages?

(I am mostly concerned about limitations arising from certain code
refactoring/analysis tools that exploit the `repository path as base path` [convention](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#PackagePaths) that
allows `go get` to look for the package online.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Go compiler and all elements of the go tool except `go get` the package import path is an almost opaque string containing the import path. You can lay out your code like you want (the compiler itself happy compiles files from different folders into one package). If you don't need or want your code to be `go get`able there is no need to use a repo path. The analysis and refactoring tools in golang.org/x/tools work on the opaque import paths (as far as I know) and do not access the network.